# When does the sum of Lipschitz constants over intervals of length 1 converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, lipschitz-functions

Given a function $f$ that is Lipschitz-continuous on every unit interval $[i,i+1]$, $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ with some Lipschitz constant $K_i$, what kind of conditions must be met for
$$
\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}K_i
$$
to converge? In particular I'm thinking of $f$ as a probability density.
This sum seems to converge for most any conventional distribution I can think of: Normal, Exponential, Chi-squared, etc. ... Any density that I can come up with as a counterexample has to pull quite a stunt by having infinitely many, smaller and smaller spikes - rather pathological.
Is there some natural assumption one could state to rule these kinds of behaviors out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that $\int_\mathbb{R} |f'|$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} |f''|$ both converge. Indeed, the Lipschitz constant of a differentiable function is the supremum of its derivative in absolute value. Note that
$$
|f'(a)-f'(b)|\le \int_{i}^{ i+1} |f''|\quad \forall a, b \in [i, i+1]
$$
and that there exists $x\in [i, i+1]$ such that $f'(x) = \int_{i}^{i+1} f'(t)\,dt$. Combining these, we get 
$$
\sup_{[i, i+1]} |f'| \le \left|\int_{i}^{i+1} f'(t)\,dt \right| + \int_{i}^{ i+1} |f''(t)|\,dt \le \int_{i}^{ i+1}(|f'(t)|+ |f''(t)|)\,dt
$$ 
as claimed.

A non-artificial density function satisfies the above, because $f$ tends to $0$ and both $f'$ and $f''$ have constant sign at infinity (they don't oscillate like a trigonometric function). These properties imply the convergence of both $\int f'$ and $\int f''$.

Comment: I'm sorry but your penultimate inequality is defeating me.

Comment: The difference between any two values of $f'$ is controlled by $f''$. Apply this to the difference between its maximal and average values. The average is just the integral of $f'$.